# realmSwift,it does not work out

Tags: swift, realm

When I use RealmSwift, the first time it worked and the data is stored. Then, I open it with RealmBrowser. Using RealmSwift after opening the Realm file with Realm Browser, the project just broke up, and the error is just like this:

```
(1) EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
(2) "Unable to open a realm at path
(3) Unsupported Realm file format version
```

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //默认的数据库
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let items = realm.objects(ConsumeItem.self)

    if items.count > 0 {
        return
    }

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(item1)
        realm.add(item2)
        realm.add(item3)
        print("++++++++")
    }
}
```

Comment: the project stop here:the error is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0                                    let realm = try! Realm()

Answer (score 0):

It means your current Realm framework does not support the current Realm file version located in your device.

Delete the app and install it again so Realm generates a new Realm file with the supported version.

If you open the Realm file with a newer version of Realm Browser, the Realm Browser will automatically update the Realm file, thus, your current Realm framework will not be able to read the file. To resolve this issue, **you have to use both the latest versions of RealmSwift framework and RealmBrowser**.

Comment: RealmSwift framework and RealmBrowser are the latest version,but it not wok,the first time the project worked well and  data is stored.     Problem is when  i run the project the second time  it  has an error .    if  i delete the database , the project work well again !      I think  the db can not create again

Comment: What's the version of your RealmSwift framework and what's the version of your Realm Browser? If you open your Realm file with Realm Browser, make sure you close Realm Browser first before using RealmSwift to open the file.